# PyCharm import matplotlib.pyplot show error

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
    y = np.sin(x)
    plt.plot(x, y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File 
"/Users/tim/workspace/Python/MachineLearn/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 63, in pylab_setup
    [backend_name], 0)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend/backend_interagg.py", line 11, in <module>
    from datalore.display import display
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm_display/datalore/display/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .display_ import *
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm_display/datalore/display/display_.py", line 5, in <module>
    from urllib.parse import urlencode
ImportError: No module named parse
```

Process finished with exit code 1

=================

Python: 2.7.16

PyCharm Professional: 2019.2

=================

btw, the code run in console mode is work

Comment: where is `from urlparse import urlparse` ?

Comment: probably you have multiple python versions on your machine and pycharm uses a different one. There is python2 and python3 and the urllib module is different in both. pycharm lets you select the python version of a project in the settings, probably changing the value there will fix your problem, as pycharm will default to using python3 nowadays

Comment: I have added an answer, hope it will help you

Comment: @576i but I have try edit code and write "import sys", "print sys.version", it shows "2.7.16"

Comment: @GOVINDDIXIT that's all code there, its a simply code, I have not import any urlparse library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple answer: disable "show plots in scientific window" (Settings -> Tools -> Python Scientific) or downgrade the PyCharm or move your project to python3
Remember to add `plt.show()` in your code.

A little more complicated. You need to write own importing hooks to find that `urllib.parse` and `urllib.request` (next line in `display_.py` file are requested.  More you can read here https://xion.org.pl/2012/05/06/hacking-python-imports/

(i'm not enough familiar with python 2 import system to write it)

Answer (score 0):

**For python 2 use**

```
from urlparse import urlparse
```

**If you need to write code which is Python2 and Python3 compatible you can use the following import**

```
try:
    from urllib.parse import urlparse
except ImportError:
     from urlparse import urlparse
```

**In your PyCharm project:**

- press Ctrl+Alt+s to open the settings
- on the left column, select Project Interpreter
- on the top right there is a list of python binaries found on your system, pick the right one
- eventually click the + button to install additional python modules, in your case, it is parse module is missing so install that one

Comment: have you tried changing python version in your pycharm?

Comment: pycharm settings Project Interpreter now is select Python 2.7, and I have try print sys.version it shows 2.7.16

Comment: what it looks to me is that your Pycharm is looking for a module which is not compatible with a particular python version.

Comment: Updated have a look

Comment: I have sovled the problem, just uncheck the checkbox "show plots in scientific window" (Settings -> Tools -> Python Scientific) and then works fine, thanks your reply

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Grzegorz Bokota, the problem is coming from the "scientific view mode" of PyCharm. This mode allows to visualise graphs and is thus calling matplotlib, and probably an incompatible version of it if you are using Python 2. This bug has been identified [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37082)  and it seems that we just have to wait for the next release to get it solved.